# Android camera2 API error in call to createCaptureSession

Tags: java, android, android-camera

Trying to get the camera2 API working, but am getting some exception when trying to create the capture session. The Surface list contains a single non-null Surface. The API docs state that the last param can be left as null to use the current thread's looper. I also have tried creating a separate thread to do this but it did not fix it. This is all happening on a Galaxy Note 5 running Lollipop

```
public void onOpened(CameraDevice camdev){
if(camdev!=null) {
    try {
        CaptureRequest.Builder captureRequest = camdev21.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW);
        captureRequest.addTarget(imageSurfaceList.get(0));
        camdev.createCaptureSession(imageSurfaceList, new CaptureSessionStateHandler(), null);
    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

Any clues? Could it be that Samsung's Camera2 implementation just sucks and I should use the depreciated Camera class (I already got that to work)?

> 11-20 00:24:15.620 3097-3651/? E/CameraDeviceClient: beginConfigure:
>   Not implemented yet.
>
> 11-20 00:24:15.620 3097-4969/? E/CameraDeviceClient: createStream:
>   bufferProducer must not be null
>
> 11-20 00:24:15.620 25601-25601/? D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
>
> 11-20 00:24:15.620 25601-25601/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION:
>   main
>
> 11-20 00:24:15.620 25601-25601/? E/AndroidRuntime: Process:
>   com.made4engineering.socialselfieapp, PID: 25601
>
> 11-20 00:24:15.620 25601-25601/? E/AndroidRuntime:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Bad argument passed to camera
>   service
>
> 11-20 00:24:15.620 25601-25601/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.hardware.camera2.utils.CameraBinderDecorator.throwOnError(CameraBinderDecorator.java:114)
>
> 11-20 00:24:15.620 25601-25601/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.hardware.camera2.utils.CameraBinderDecorator$CameraBinderDecoratorListener.onAfterInvocation(CameraBinderDecorator.java:73)
>
> 11-20 00:24:15.620 25601-25601/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.hardware.camera2.utils.Decorator.invoke(Decorator.java:81)
>
> 11-20 00:24:15.620 25601-25601/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Proxy.invoke(Proxy.java:397)
>
> 11-20 00:24:15.620 25601-25601/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   $Proxy2.createStream(Unknown Source)
>
> 11-20 00:24:15.620 25601-25601/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl.configureOutputsChecked(CameraDeviceImpl.java:378)
>
> 11-20 00:24:15.620 25601-25601/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl.createCaptureSession(CameraDeviceImpl.java:437)
>
> 11-20 00:24:15.620 25601-25601/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   com.made4engineering.socialselfieapp.CameraHandler$CameraStateHandler.onOpened(CameraHandler.java:471)
>
> 11-20 00:24:15.620 25601-25601/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl$1.run(CameraDeviceImpl.java:118)
>
> 11-20 00:24:15.620 25601-25601/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>
> 11-20 00:24:15.620 25601-25601/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>
> 11-20 00:24:15.620 25601-25601/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
>
> 11-20 00:24:15.620 25601-25601/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6897)
>
> 11-20 00:24:15.620 25601-25601/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>
> 11-20 00:24:15.620 25601-25601/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>
> 11-20 00:24:15.620 25601-25601/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
>
> 11-20 00:24:15.620 25601-25601/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)